# cannot borrow `args` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: loops, rust, borrow-checker

```rust
let mut args: Vec<String> = args().collect();
for mut i in 0..args.len() {
  if args[i].contains("-type") {
    project_type = args[i].split("=").last().unwrap();
    args.remove(i);
    i-=1;
  }
}
```

I'm very new to rust and want to know why this code gives me the error "cannot borrow 'args' as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable" and how i can fix it

I'm trying to check if the args Vec contains an item like "-type=some_type", then put "some_type" in a variable called "project_type". Finally I want to remove the item "-type=some_type" from the list and keep searching.

edit: if I'm doing what I'm trying to do wrong, i would appreciate a better solution.

Comment: What is the point of `args.remove(i)`? Is there a reason that needs to be removed? It's nearly always a bad idea to modify the collection you are looping over.

Comment: yes there is, i use exact values to find the places of items in args, if its not deleted then it messes up everything else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`str::split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split) doesn't create new string objects, it returns references to the existing one. So your `project_type` variable is a reference to a string in `args`. When you `remove` from `args`, you invalidate all of those references.

You can convert a `&str` to a `String` and break the reference with `.to_owned()`

```
project_type = args[i].split("=").last().unwrap().to_owned();
```

Now, `for` loops in Rust iterate *over* data structures. As such, your `i -= 1` trick won't work. `i` will just get reset back to where it was at the next iteration. If you want to do this the way you're currently doing it, you want  a `while` loop.

```
let mut i = 0
while i < args.len() {
  if ... {
    ...
  } else {
    i += 1;
  }
}
```

However, let's think about this a bit more functionally. What it sounds like you want is to find a matching element of a vector (and its index) and then do something with it. So let's break that down into two separate problems.

We use [`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) to get a collection together with its index, and [`find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) to search it. Since it looks like you expect the value to be there, we'll `unwrap` it and panic if it's not there. If you want to handle the error, convert this to a `match`.

```
let (idx, element) = args.iter().find(|x| x.contains("-type")).unwrap();
```

Once we have it, we can do our work on `element` to get the project type.

```
project_type = element.split("=").last().unwrap().to_owned();
```

Note that at this point `project_type` does not depend on `args` at all. `element` does, and Rust may be smart enough to see this, but let's just be perfectly safe and make sure `element` gets dropped before we modify `args`. Once there are no more references to `args`, we can mutably borrow to do the `remove` operation.

```
let idx = {
  let (idx, element) = args.iter().enumerate().find(|(_, x)| x.contains("-type")).unwrap();
  project_type = element.split("=").last().unwrap().to_owned();
  idx
}
args.remove(idx);
```